# How to remove the OpenSolaris ZFS dump device

Tags: solaris, zfs, opensolaris, dump

The ZFS dump device is [used only for debugging problems](https://serverfault.com/q/484534/58001). In this case, I have decided the risk vs reward is such that I should delete the dump device to make room for other storage.

I am able to disable save-core (copy from dump device to `/var/crash`) using `dumpadm -n`, but when I run `zfs destroy rpool/dump`, I still get
`cannot destroy 'rpool/dump': dataset is busy`, indicating that `dumpadm -n` was insufficient.

How can I disable and remove this dedicated dump device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify another location for dumpadm to use crash dumps instead of just disabling them.

`dumpadm -d swap`

Source: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.solaris.opensolaris.zfs/19529

Comment: This won't work for me because I removed the swap device to save disk space. There was so much free RAM that swap could not have improved performance.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but if you read the link it suggest that even you don't have a suitable swap device, telling it to use swap  will set it to 'none' so it's no longer using your dump device. Can't hurt to try.

Comment: I already tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Since you're just trying to reclaim the space, can you resize the  dump volume to something silly small like `zfs set volsize=1M rpool/dump`?

Comment: Yep. That silly solution seems to be the best I can do.

Comment: If 1M doesn't work (out of space), try a larger value like 8M, which worked for me on OmniOS/Illumos.

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://www.en.sysadmin-cookbook.net/zfs/#toc-gen-14

```
zdb -d tank | grep rpool/dump
```

and now `zfs destroy` found datasets.

Comment: I might give it a try next time I'm working on a staging server, but at first glance it looks like the linked page is solving `dataset already exists`, while my question is about `dataset is busy`. So maybe it will work and maybe it won't...

Comment: This looks like a very helpful command. I have an idea on how `zdb` could make my reporting scripts more accurate.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. No results output from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ZFS volume something like:

```
zfs create -V 2G rpool/dump1
```

Using the dumpadm utility change the directory to `rpool/dump1`, e.g.:

```
dumpadm -d /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/dump1
```

Then you can destroy the `rpool/dump` without any issues.

```
zfs destroy rpool/dump
```

Hope this helps to resize your dump devices or destroy dump devices without dataset busy error.